# Using Apply in Function

Tags: r

I have the following matrix in R

```
mat<-matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)  
dimnames(mat)[[1]] <- letters[1:10]  
dimnames(mat)[[2]] <- 1:10
```

and i want to use the apply function.  When I'm on the studio's prompt I do not have any particular issue 
For example

```
sumRows<-apply(mat,2,sum)  
divMat<-apply(mat,1,"/",sumRows)
```

The problems start when i'm trying to encapsulate the above code on a function E.G.

```
calcDivision<-function(mat)  
{  
 sumRows<-apply(mat,2,sum)  
 divMat<-apply(mat,1,"/",sumRows)
 return(divMat)
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: It all runs fine for me. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Runs fine here to. What happens when you call the function ?

Comment: You did do calcDivision(mat) after you made the function - right?

Comment: It return the ominus Error in apply(mat, 2, sum) : dim(X) must have a positive length when I try to use result <-apply(mat,1,calcDivision)

Comment: Agree with @Chargraff in terms of needing more info. If you are expecting `sumRows` and `divMat` to be available post-function call that will not happen as they are scoped to the `calcDivision()` function. It should be returning what you would have gotten directly from the `apply(mat,1,"/",sumRows)` call in the second code box.

Comment: I figured it out guys Thanks for the help you should use directly call of the function result<-calcDivision(mat) instead of result<-apply(mat,1,calcDivision)

Comment: BTW, for this type of operation you could use `sweep`.  In your case: `t(sweep(mat, 2, colSums(mat), FUN = "/"))` .